# Inherit more classes if certain macros are defined

Tags: c++

I have a macro `ROOF_EXISTS` that may or may not be defined during compilation time.

The macro is currently used to indicate if a class should be inherited or not in the following way:

```
#ifdef ROOF_EXISTS
class building : public door, public roof, public window
#else
class building : public door, public window
#endif
```

I also want to add 2 more macros which adds additional classes if they are defined.
However, if I do that, I quickly run into a lot of copying and pasting and exponential increase in code, which becomes messy.

Is there a clean way to use the macros to conditionally add (or remove) classes that need to be inherited?

Comment: That looks like a terrible design. Why not using a variadic template instead? What's the purpose actually?

Comment: I don't think you're going about this the right way. Inheritance describes an "is-a" relationship. Why is a building a window? Why is a building a door?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your design. Inheritance encapsulates "isa" relationship. A building is not a door

Comment: Looks like a case for the [_Decorator Pattern_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator).

Comment: How will you use those extra inherited types without adding the same `#ifdef` macros throughout your code?

Comment: I might have given a terrible example for classes to inherit from... I should have probably used A B  and C like the answer suggested.

Comment: @user43825 If your real classes have the same semantics as shown in your example you should rather go with the _Decorator Pattern_.

Comment: Why would a class sometimes exist and sometimes not exist? Why not simply let it exist? Also, why would another class change in appearance like that? Either a building is required to have a roof or it is not. Why don't you go like `RoofedBuilding: public Building, public Roof`` instead? (Not that it would make any sense that a building is a roof.)

Comment: Let me try to put this simply: the objection raised here is that inheritance models an "is-a" relationship. By changing the base classes, you're asking to define a class that under some circumstances *is* one thing, but under other circumstances, it *is* something else. Changing the names of the base classes won't change that fundamental fact; either way, it seems to be a fairly fundamental problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class Test: public A
#ifdef TEST
, public B
#else
, public C
#endif
{
};
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.